# Authenticating user into Cognos 11 via REST URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, restful-authentication, cognos

I'm currently working on fixing a connection between a MVC4 application and IBM Cognos 11 application.

Previously, when moving between the MVC app and Cognos 10.2, we would redirect the user with their authentication within the URL.  This wasn't desired but was how the system was set up initially when our team received the project.

Our team has now upgraded to Cognos 11.  In doing so, we've lost the usage of this previous redirect (we get an error and the user isn't authenticated into Cognos).

My question is, is there a way to authenticate a user without installing the Cognos SDK (we have it but have yet to integrate it)?  I was looking into the REST URL that it uses but it appears that to consume it, I need to have the SDK to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Mashup Service may be what you want, that's a REST-oriented interface that supports authentication and doesn't require you to install the SDK. Here's a link that discusses how to login to Mashup Service:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21660206

I tried the URL in that technote to get a description of required credentials on a Cognos 11 environment, and found that I had to tweak it because we aren't using a gateway web server. I found I needed to add a port, and omit /ibmcognos, so the URL that worked for me was more like

http://[ServerName]:[Port]/bi/v1/disp/rds/auth/logon?xmlData=

Finally, for more doc on Mashup Service, go to

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_cms.doc/c_rass_gs.html